# turtlebot obstacle avoidance using point cloud data

Tags: ros, avoidance, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to understand and write a C++ program in gazebo/ros to make turtlebot avoids obstacles while moving forward using pointcloud data. How to get started with this? I have already created a node to subscribe point cloud data and visualize this in rviz.

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201497/turtlebot-obstacle-avoidance-using-point-cloud-data/) by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Best to learn by example.

Take a look at the code here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_follower

You are essentially looking to do the opposite, avoid the obstacles instead of following them.

---

Originally posted by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) with karma: 101 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-01-25**:
Thank you.
I would also like to know, is someone did the same thing, obstacle avoidance using point cloud data so that I don’t have to reinvent the wheel?